# How to create a WPF-tab control as chevron list?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have a WPF tab control. but I would like to change the tab item style. The default style is square. I need to make it like a chevron list. Each block in that as hexagon.

EDIT:
[image: Please see the attached image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you want... could you post a sketch?

Comment: Please see the attached image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a quick example made with Kaxaml:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="chevronTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,-7,0" Height="30">
              <Path Data="M0,0 10,0 10,30 0,30 10,15"
                    Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
              <Grid>
                <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="10,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
              </Grid>
              <Path Data="M0,0 10,15 0,30"
                    Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />                  
            </StackPanel>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid>  
    <TabControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource chevronTabItemStyle}">
      <TabItem Header="Design" Background="DarkSlateBlue" />
      <TabItem Header="Plan" Background="DarkCyan" />
      <TabItem Header="Build" Background="LightSkyBlue" />
      <TabItem Header="Test" Background="SandyBrown" />
      <TabItem Header="Evaluate" Background="SteelBlue" />
    </TabControl>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

You will probably need to adjust a few properties, but it's roughly what you described...

[image]

Comment: Wow, very nice - this looks perfect for what I'm looking for.. thanks for providing a really solid base!

Answer (score 3):

Thomas Levesque your answer is beautiful!

There is a little problem with **foreground color**, move property into TextBlock prevent all tab to be colored White

In this way we can change the color of the header if properties IsEnable or Selected are valued.

```
<Style x:Key="TestNewTabStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">                        
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,-7,0" Height="30">
                        <Path Data="M0,0 10,0 10,30 0,30 10,15" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Grid >
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            <TextBlock Name="HeaderArrow" Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="15,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"**/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Path Data="M0,0 10,15 0,30" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="HeaderArrow" Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter TargetName="HeaderArrow" Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="HeaderArrow" Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```